# Proving the existence of a periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a particular homework problem, I need to show that the differential equation:
\begin{equation*}
y^{\prime\prime}(x) - \frac{1-(y^{\prime}(x))^{2}}{1+(y^{\prime}(x))^{2}}y^{\prime} + y(x) = 0
\end{equation*}
has a periodic solution.
The problem statement outlines a multi-step procedure as a hint.
One part of the process suggests replacing 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1-(y^{\prime}(x))^{2}}{1+(y^{\prime}(x))^{2}}y^{\prime}
\end{equation*}
by a larger term
\begin{equation*}
1-y^{\prime}
\end{equation*}
such that the resulting equation 
\begin{equation*}
z^{\prime\prime} - (1-z^{\prime}) + z = 0
\end{equation*}
has a solution 
with $z^{\prime}(x) >0$ for $0 < x < 1$,
$z(0) = A = -z(1)$,
and
$z^{\prime}(0) = z^{\prime}(1) = 0$

For this new differential equation I find that
\begin{equation*}
z(x) = c_{1}e^{-x/2}\sin\left(\frac{x\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+c_{2}e^{-x/2}\cos\left(\frac{x\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) + 1
\end{equation*}

I also find that
$z(0) = c_{2}+1 = A$,
but I do not find that $z(0)=-z(1)$.  Thus, I wonder where I am going wrong.

Comment: Yes, this was given as part of the hint.  Also, $A$ is a constant.

Comment: Was the form of $z(x)$ given in the hint? There might be constants within the trigonometric functions, which would make $z(0)= -z(1) = z(2)$.

Comment: The phaseportrait command of Maple confirms [that](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdzuoanhe679hsb/phaseportrait.pdf): see the brown line.

Comment: No, the form of $z(x)$ was not given in the hint.  I found that myself.

Comment: Thanks for the phase portrait!  It is very illuminating.

Comment: Each attempt I make at solving for $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$, and $A$ gets me $c_{1} = c_{2} = 0$, but this in turn leads to z(1) = 1 which is not right.

Comment: The larger equation of $z$ was given in the problem, but my guess is that it can be shown that for some particular solution $y$ the two differential equations will agree.  We want $z$ to give us a bounding region.  I set $(1-z^{\prime}) = \frac{1-(y^{\prime})^{2}}{1+(y^{\prime})^{2}}y^{\prime}$. I used long division to find $y^{\prime}=z^{\prime}-1$, but I am not sure if this is correct. While showing some of my work to a professor, it was confirmed that there must be a bug in the problem, i.e. the constraint $z(0) = -z(1)$ is not correct. It should be something more like $z(0) = -z(2\pi/3)$.

Comment: That last equality should read as $z(0)=−z(2π/\sqrt{3})$.